# Covariance Identity

Tags: statistics

[image]

I don't follow the 3rd and 5th line of the solution. Why in the third line, can we take the matrix $A$ outside to the left of the expectation and also why can we take the matrix $B^T$ outside to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case is simply a matter of moving a constant factor out side the expectation operation.   This works whether the constant is a matrix or a scalar.   One distinction is, of course, that matrix multiplication is not commutative.

$$\mathsf E[(A~\mathbf U)~\mathbf V]=A~\mathsf E[\mathbf{U~V}]$$

The second case is the same only first the product is transposed.   Recall the transposition of a product of matrices is the reverse ordered product of their transpositions.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E[\mathbf U~(B~\mathbf V)^\top] ~=~& \mathsf E[\mathbf U~ \mathbf V^\top~B^\top] \\=~&\mathsf E[\mathbf U~\mathbf V^\top]~B^\top\end{align}$$

Putting it together
$$\mathsf E[(A~\mathbf U)~(B~\mathbf V)^\top]=A~\mathsf E[\mathbf{U~V^\top}]~B^\top$$

$\Box$

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B^T$ are constant factors. Therefore they can be factored out. In general it is $E(aX)=aE(X)$. $X$ and $Y$ are matrices containing random variables. $A$ is left of the two summands $X$ and $E(X)$. Thus it has to be factored out to the left side. Similar reasoning for factoring out $B$